# FOR %%a in (A B C...) statement pulling up error

Tags: loops, batch-file

I'm using a for %%a in a loop statement;

```
for %%a in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do (
IF EXIST %%a:\file.id SET USBDRV=%%a:&& GOTO xcopypart
```

Which then goes on to perform an xcopy execution. The issue is, if the device/computer has say, an SD card slot etc and the device is appearing greyed-out under Computer, it will ask the user to *insert disk into removable disk.*

This is problematic because computer configs are different - some have SD card slots, some don't - and because it's part of an application I cannot have users facing this error message constantly with the only alternative being they disable existing hardware to make it work.

Is there a switch or override I can use that will skip disks that are 'empty'?

cheers for your time

-Julian

Comment: You could probably add another if statement to check 'dir /b driveletter' and proceed to the next step only when 'dir /b driveletter'  is not empty/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
set "USBDRV="
for %%a in (
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
) do vol %%a: >nul 2>&1 && ( 
    if exist "%%a:\file.id" set "USBDRV=%%a:" & goto xcopypart 
)
```

This first uses a `vol` command to test if the drive is ready. If there is no errorlevel, then the drive is tested for the presence of the file.

Comment: sorry @MC, should have clarified that it's wrapped in a looping goto statement;

`:find
set "USBDRV="
for %%a in (
    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
) do vol %%a: >nul && ( 
    if exist "%%a:\file.id" set "USBDRV=%%a:" & goto xcopypart 
)
goto find`


The code you've suggested just pulls up a looping 'The handle is invalid'

Comment: @JulianWhite, sorry, i forgot to redirect stderr to hide the output to stderr. Code updated.

Comment: Wonderful, this worked perfectly thank you very much! Adding `:FIND` at the beginning and `GOTO FIND` at the end also relooped the statement beautifully as well.